# Update Nova resource with a empty string as default for field

Tags: laravel-nova

I have an existing data model that has a unique indexed string field that defaults to an empty string.

I added an $attributes property to the model to default it to an empty string when creating a new object.  That works just fine.

However when updating the object and the field remains empty, it will fail since the field is returned as null and the DB field is not nullable.  I am not sure of the impact of making that field nullable().  Too much code to dig through so I can't change it.

I am thinking I can observe for an event, and change the value from null to empty string there, but I would rather take care of this in Nova.

Is there anyway to tell Nova an empty field should be saved as an empty string?

Answer (score 0):

Short version: no.

Long version:
This cannot be set in Nova. An empty string will be passed as null in the HTTP request. This behaviour is part of Laravel's core. The only way to make sure it isn't passed as an empty string from Nova is to put form validation on it and make it a required field.

If you don't mind changing code on the Laravel app level, you can disable this behaviour by removing the `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` middleware in your app's Kernel.

*/app/Http/Kernel.php*

```
protected $middleware = [
    ...
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class, // remove this line
];
```

However, if the DB field isn't nullable, the field has to have a value anyway right? I'd suggest putting an accessor on the model to check for null values:

```
public function setMyFieldAttribute($val)
{
    $this->attributes['my_field'] = $val ?? '';
}
```

Or, if you want to be really certain it always has a value, add an observer for the saving event (as you already mentioned), and make sure the field has a value before the data is actually saved.